# Regex, Forbid dot (.) as a the last character

Tags: java, regex

Does anybody knows how to write Regex for condition: "Dot is not allowed as the last character".
My Regex is:

```
"^[0-9A-Za-z!$'( )+,-;=@\\[\\]_`^]+$"
```

How can I cover the condition: 
*Name.png* (**is allowed**)   *VS*  *Name.***(**is forbbiden**)

Comment: Are you sure what your pattern is matching? Note that a dot is matched with this pattern as `,-;` range includes it. If it is OK, all you need to add is a `(?<!\\.)` before/after `$`.

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? You can just use `String.charAt(String.length()-1).equals(".")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not understand whether you need an extension of your regex or a simple regex that solves your problem "Dot is not allowed as the last character"? For the second problem, one solution is:

```
.*(?<!\.)$
```

This should work for java, but NOT for javascript.

Answer (score 7):

Why you simply don't use [**`String::endsWith`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) :

```
String str = "Name.png";
if (str.endsWith(".")) {
    System.out.println("NOT CORRECT");
} else {
    System.out.println("CORRECT");
}
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I think your print statements should be the other way around according to OP.